# Ajax always go on 'Error' (C# MVC 5) on Cross-Domain request

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cross-domain

I have this C# method:

**C#**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public JsonResult PostOnCRM(string textBoxFirstName, string textBoxCountry, string textBoxLastName, string textBoxEmail, string textBoxTitle, string textBoxTelephone, string textBoxCompany, string textBoxWebsite, string textAreaNote, string checkBoxUpdates)
{

        bool isValidEmail = Regex.IsMatch(textBoxEmail,
        @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
        @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));

        if (!isValidEmail)
            throw new Exception("E-mail is not a valid one");
        LeadInformation lead = new LeadInformation()
        {
            Subject = "Web site",
            FirstName = textBoxFirstName,
            LastName = textBoxLastName,
            JobTitle = textBoxTitle,
            Address1_Country = textBoxCountry,
            EmailAddress1 = textBoxEmail,
            MobilePhone = textBoxTelephone,
            WebsiteUrl = textBoxWebsite,
            Description = textAreaNote,
            DoNotEmail = checkBoxUpdates.Contains("Yes") ? true : false
        };


        //Some method that works well go here

        return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Your message successfuly sent!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And in my view, this Ajax call

**Ajax**

```
$("#formContact").submit(function (evt) {
evt.preventDefault();

var formdata = $('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    url: 'http://localhost:59289/Lead/PostOnCRM',
    data: formdata,
    success: function (response) {
        alert('success!');
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert('Error! try again later');
    }
});
});
```

The method performs perfectly. Does the insert in the database but when it returns to the ajax method it always lands on the 'error' and does not return the response I've sent. What can it be?

Sorry for taking the parameters in this way (especially bool value thing) and for not use a Bind or anything, but this is not relevant to the question

I asked it at Portuguese StackOverflow but without a good answer.

Here, a print of my browser
https://postimg.cc/image/e86q3hcol/

Comment: What is the error detail returned in the error response?

Comment: Run your controller with the debugger; step through to verify it returns successfully. Next, watch the network request with the browser's debug monitor and verify a successful response status code, headers, message. Display the error you receive `error: function(jqxhr, status, error) { console.log(jqxhr, status, error); }`.

Comment: Stinky, it's just an "abort". there is nothing on 'error' response.

Comment: Jansen, it's always a 200 code status. 
Error:""
status: "error

Comment: i am receiving a object. the only thing i can tell is that its have and length 1 on abort :| i did not found anything that helps. I should look for what?

I posted at postman where i get my json response correctly but at ajax it's returning on error :/

Comment: No where in your question did you mention it was a cross origin request (and now you have deleted your own answer). Either delete the question (as it stands it of no use to anyone and others will waste their time trying to answer), or edit it with the relevant details and un-delete you own answer and accept it.

Comment: your are right. I didn't thought that this could be the reason. I've un-deleted the answer. i decided to wait a little bit to check if that is the real answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My boss resolved my problem in 5 minutes (i tried by 2 days) with

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

On web.config :|

I don't know why. Some one can explain me?

I Forgot to say but it's a cross origin request :|

Comment: Too many things can go wrong easily. If you mentions CORS in original question, we could have point it right away. `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />` might pose security risk depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ***you should never use Regular Expression to validate email address. Look at [this](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).***

Second, you want to use ***Model*** in ASP.Net MVC, instead of declaring multiple parameters in action method.

Please do it property. If you still have question, please come back and ask again. Here is a working example -

View

```
@model UserModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
        <button id="btnSubmit" type="button">Submit</button>
    }
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                var data = {
                    Email: $("#Email").val()
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "@Url.Action("PostOnCRM", "Lead")",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert('success!');
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert('Error! try again later');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

### View

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller

```
public class LeadController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {    
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult PostOnCRM(UserModel model)
    {
        bool isValidEmail = IsValidEmail(model.Email);

        if (!isValidEmail)
            throw new Exception("E-mail is not a valid one");

        // ...

        return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Your message successfuly sent!" });
    }

    public static bool IsValidEmail(string email)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
            return false;

        try
        {
            email = new MailAddress(email).Address;
            return true;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not say what causes the issue, because the code did not follow the best practices in ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: Yes, i know. It's a long sad story :(